# querying mongodb (mongoose) for a timespan in subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an mongoose schema that looks like this:

```
var wishSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    foo: {
        bar: String,
        fooDate: Date
    },
});
```

I'm trying to query all documents where the fooDate is after a certain date. I came up with this solution but it doesn't seem to work quite right:

```
{
   foo: {
       $elemMatch: {
           fooDate: { $gt: new Date('2014-01-01') }
       }
   }
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is for arrays. The query you are looking for is:

```
{'foo.fooDate': {$gt: new Date('2014-01-01') }}
```

`$elemMatch` would work for the following schema, and return results if at least one item from `foo` array match specified query (or all specified queries):

```
var wishSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    foo: [
        bar: String,
        fooDate: Date
    ]
});
```

If you need to run only one query on inner array of documents it is better to just use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```
{'foo.fooDate': {$gt: new Date('2014-01-01') }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! I tried your solution and it seems like it does not work as I intended it to do. Nevertheless I consider your answer as correct and am sure that the failure lies in my setup...